# can i use jquery multiple id selectors with && as seperator for getting result satisfied by all the ids?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, magento

I want to enable or disable submit button depending on multiple other button clicks so my question is 
    can jquery multiple id selectors have `'&&'` as separator for getting result satisfied by all the `ids`? is this valid?

For example code:

```
<script> 
var button = $("#button1" && "#button2" && "#button3" && "#button4");
button.on("click",function(e) {
        submitButt.prop("disabled",false); // NOT a toggle
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You [may](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) use `#button1,#button2,button3`

Comment: ...but I'd rather have some common attribute for that purpose (e.g. `class`)

Comment: U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg thanks for the suggestion of using a class but my question is it valid to use && on the multiple  ids

Comment: ...and that was the very first comment I have posted - use comma instead of `&&` and refer to official tutorial I have linked